# Central Admin Site 500 Error After Database Move

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration

I followed the directions to move my database server to another this went fine and all other sites are up and running just when i try to go to the central admin site i get an immediate 500 error. I checked the error logs and nothing is there. Any Ideas on how to rebuild the central admin site.

Comment: Are you sure the App pool of central administration is running ? have you changed something on its web config ? Are you tried to run SP config wizard after moving ?

Comment: what  sharepoint version you are?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did figure this out i just needed to provision the Central Admin Site all is working now. That being said the app pool was running it was a 500 Error which is a coding error. So i am sure the app pool was running. this was SharePoint 2013.